# Crack by windowsill

Tags: walls, windows, patching-drywall

[image: stone windowsill under a window with a large hole to the right of it]

Hello! I bought a house 6 months ago and we’ve noticed recently that every window on the top floor has a large crack/hole on the sides of the window sill. Could somebody tell me what is happening and what needs to happen to fix it? Is it structural or cosmetic? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

If just the holes and the window sills are tight, then it was probably a toothpaste patch done when selling.

Should do a proper patch job, but matching the paint might be hard.

Might be able to make a paint border with a different colour and make it a design statement.